# Angular 5 timeout when requesting a detail component using the full URL

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've got an Angular 5 app behind an NGINX web server and I have a strange behavior when trying to access "directly" a detail component through its full URL resulting on a gateway timeout...

If I navigate to my `www.myapp.com` then to `masterComponent` (URL then would be `www.myapp.com/masterComponent`) then `detailId1` for example (full URL of the resource would be `www.myapp.com/masterComponent/detailId1`) then the detail renders correctly in a timely manner. If however I paste the same URL (`www.myapp.com/masterComponent/detailId1` in the browser) I get a timeout. I don't think has anything to do with the `PathLocationStrategy` but in any case this is my routing setup - quite simple by the way:

```
const enableTracing: boolean = environment.enableRoutingTracing;

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'masterComponent/:id', component: MyDetailsComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing}) ],
    providers : [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Do you know why could it be happening?

**UPDATE**

A sample error would be:

```
2018/02/01 16:59:34 [error] 8#8: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW, server: myapp.com, request: "GET /masterComponent/1 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.18.0.5:4000/masterComponent/1", host: "myapp.com"
```

Another interesting bit is that the "http_referer" is being logged with a dash (-):

```
myapp.com XX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW - - [01/Feb/2018:16:59:34 +0000] "GET /masterComponent/1 HTTP/2.0" 504 585 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

The logging section can be found here:

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl#L62

```
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

I'm using the automatic nginx proxy template generation from https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl

Comment: do you have any resolvers or guards which aren't enabled but should?

Comment: I have no guards and as far as I'm aware no resolvers either